# Export Specific Records from MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, export, record, mysql-workbench

I have databases in my system and also put database on web server also, so when I update my system database data I ll have to then `replace or add data into web database`.

but

problem is that I am doing changes in database to some specific record frequently for testing purpose.
So I want some mechanism that will used to export some specific records to sql file with insert statement.

Suppose I have made change in table tbl1 and added 10 records to it.
So right now I am manually adding or replacing whole table on web database.

So is there any mechanism in MySql or in Workbench using that I can export specific records.

Any Help for that.

Comment: check Replicaton http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Answer (score 1):

The only automatic solution is to use replication, but that is probably not a good solution for your scenario. So what remains is some manual process. Here are some ideas:

1. Write a script that [writes specific records into a dump file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).
   Then use a different script to [load this dump file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) into your
   target server.
2. If you frequently change the same records you could create a script
   with insert statements that you edit for each new value and run
   against both your local and your remote (web) server.